# How do I add a event listener for IPCmain.on?

Tags: javascript, electron, event-handling

I'm trying to make a button for my app where when you press it, a "note card" pops up. But right now when I'm trying to pass in "event" into one of the parameters for my IPCmain.on it is saying that its deprecated. What should I do?

main.js

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron'); 

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow); 

app.on('window-all-closed', ()=> {
  app.quit();
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0){
    createWindow(); 
  }
}); 

ipcMain.on('createNote', () => {
  const noteText = 'New Note'; 
  mainWindow.webContents.send('noteCreated', noteText);
});
```

create.js

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron'); 

document.getElementById('createButton').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  ipcRenderer.send('createNote'); 
}); 

ipcRenderer.on('noteCreated', (noteText) => {
  const noteContainer = document.getElementById('noteContainer'); 
  const noteCard = document.createElement('div'); 
  noteCard.textContent = noteText; 
  noteContainer.appendChild(noteCard); 
});
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
    <meta charset = "UTF-8"> 
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="create.js"> </script>
    <title> ToDo </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="Header">
      <h1> Header </h1>
      <button id="createButton"> Create </button>
    </div>
    <div id="noteContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to pass in my variable "createNote" from create.js into the parameter, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When getting an error, it is a good idea to check all relevant [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer). There, we can see that your listener for the `noteCreated` event in the renderer process should have a very different signature.

In fact, the documentation lists two parameters Electron will pass to the listener function, namely `event`, which will be of the type `IpcRendererEvent`, and `...args`, which will be of type `any[]`. The dots tell you that you can expect multiple arguments at the spot of `args`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

`args` will be whatever you have passed to `webContents.send()`. Thus, you should modify your listener function to

```js
ipcRenderer.on('noteCreated', (event, noteText) => {
  const noteContainer = document.getElementById('noteContainer'); 
  const noteCard = document.createElement('div'); 
  noteCard.textContent = noteText; 
  noteContainer.appendChild(noteCard); 
});
```

The naming of the parameters is irrelevant, only their order and position matters: The first argument will always be an `IpcRendererEvent` (which lets you communicate with the sender of the message directy) followed by any arguments you have supplied.